# Selenium - Get elements html rather Text Value

Tags: c#, html-parsing, selenium-webdriver

Via that code i have extracted all desired text out of a html document

```
private void RunThroughSearch(string url)
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    INavigation nav = driver.Navigate();
    nav.GoToUrl(url);

    var div = driver.FindElement(By.Id("results"));
    var element = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("sa_wr"));
}
```

though as i need to refine results of extracted document

```
Container
    HEADER -> Title of a given block
    Url -> Link to the relevant block
    text -> body of a given block
/Container
```

as u can see in my code i am able to get the value of the text part 
as a text value , that was fine, but what if i want to have 
the value of the container as **HTML** and not the extracted text ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Header"> Title...</div>
    <div class="Url"> www.example.co.il</div>
    <div class="ResConent"> bla.. </div>
</div>
```

so the container is  about 10 times in a page 
i need to extract it's innerHtml .

any ideas ? (using Selenium)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find the element first, then use [IJavaScriptExecutor](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/IJavascriptExecutor.cs) to get the inner HTML.

```
var element = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("sa_wr"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
if (js != null) {
    string innerHtml = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
}
```

Answer (score 53):

This seemed to work for me, and is less code:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("sa_wr"));
var innerHtml = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: when I use this error pops saying element does not have "GetAttribute" attribute. Help?

Comment: This solution is works for better than above answers. Thanks

Comment: Far better answer. You can also use outerHTML if that's what you need too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [SQA-SO](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12477/45101)

```
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "New text!";");
```