# how to copy site content and convert to .txt file selenium C #

Tags: c#, selenium, type-conversion

I'm doing so, but I can not convert iwebElement to toString

```
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
           clicarLink = drive.FindElement(By.ClassName("LC20lb"));
             clicarLink.Click();

            copiarConteudo = drive.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);

            copiarConteudo.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "a");
```

Comment: If C# cannot do it, you could resort to running javascript instead

Comment: [selenium-get-elements-html-rather-text-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862100/selenium-get-elements-html-rather-text-value)

Comment: how would you do with javascript? Iloyd

Comment: did you click on the link and look at the accepted answer?

Comment: @lloyd The linked answer you are referring to is extracting the HTML, not the text as requested.

Comment: Did you try `copiarConteudo.Text`?

Comment: Try getting the 'value' attribute

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _site content_? What do you want to convert into `.txt` format?

Comment: I want to copy texts that are on the site.

Comment: yes @JeffC but not convert webElement for String

Comment: That's not going to be an error for the code you have posted and what I referred to. Please post the actual code you used and the full error message.